# Android Bluetooth Device CoD returns 1F00

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, zebra-printers

I am trying to connect to a Zebra ZD420 printer from the android app. But when I try to connect to it, it returns bluetoothClass as "**1f00**". I converted to hex, which is **1111100000000**. I checked in this [link](https://www.ampedrftech.com/datasheets/cod_definition.pdf) to get the category, which says this - "**Uncategorized, specific device code not specified**" .

This device was earlier used by others and they had no issue. But I seem to be getting this problem. Can someone please tell me what is causing this issue and how I can resolve it?